# Haskell Reversed Number Digit List

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am new to Haskell and I am trying to turn an int into a reversed digit list(of ints).

What I have is:

```
Lnat 0 = [0]
Lnat x = [mod x 10] ++ Lnat (div x 10)
```

However I get the error "Not in scope: data constructor 'Lnat'" on both lines and it crashes trying to load the file.

Could you please explain the root of this and how to fix it?

Comment: Functions you define must have a name starting with a lowercase letter. Use e.g. `lnat`. Uppercase letters are reserved for constructors of values in data types.

Comment: functions start with lowercase letters, types and constructors start with capitals

Comment: use lowercase initial for function names.  Uppercase initial means constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All values must start with a lowercase character. If it starts with a capital or `:` then that value is a data constructor, to be used in `data` declarations. This is what you'll want to change your function to:

```
lnat 0 = [0]
lnat x = mod x 10 : lnat (div x 10)
```

Note that I also changed the inefficient `++` operator to `:` to add a bit more speed.